# Updating Android Application when it's not in Playstore

Tags: android

How can I notify the user that the Application can be updated if it's not placed in the Google Market Place? Is there any way to notify the user through the app that some updates are available.

Comment: Try to search what is an OTA service is:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use GCM for this purpose.
for more detail  http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html